# First attempt at a minimal react-bootstrap page not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying out react-bootstrap with a simple page with one menu button and a modal that should popup. The error is fairly deep into react code and react-bootstrap code.

The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid Argument Type, must only provide functions, undefined, or null.(anonymous function) 
@ createChainedFunction.js:15n
@ createChainedFunction.js:13t.render 
@ NavItem.js:67_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext 
@ react.min.js:13_renderValidatedComponent 
....    
@ react.min.js:14render 
@ react.min.js:14(anonymous function) 
@ reactcs.js:102transform.run 
@ browser.min.js:4exec 
@ browser.min.js:4(anonymous function) 
@ browser.min.js:4xhr.onreadystatechange 
@ browser.min.js:4.
```

Here is my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Example site">
        <meta name="keywords"
            content="score, swift">
        <title>Example</title>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/css/csreact.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

        </div>
        <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <HomePage />,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );
    </script>
        <!-- =============== PAGE VENDOR SCRIPTS ===============-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.30.0/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
</script>    
        <!-- =============== APP SCRIPTS ===============-->
        <script src="js/reactcs.js"></script>
        <script src="js/js4k.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the javascript

```
'use strict';

/**
 * 
 */
var Nav = ReactBootstrap.Nav;
var Navbar = ReactBootstrap.Navbar;
var NavItem = ReactBootstrap.NavItem;
var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
var Form = ReactBootstrap.Form;
var FormControl = ReactBootstrap.FormControl;
var FormGroup = ReactBootstrap.FormGroup;
var ControlLabel = ReactBootstrap.ControlLabel;
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;

var HomePage = React.createClass({

    openLogin: function () {
        ReactDOM.render(LoginModal, document.getElementById('container'));
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
  <div>
  <Navbar inverse>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="#">Server API example</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} onClick="openLogin">Login</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar> 
  </div>
        );
    }  
});

var LoginModal = React.createClass({

    login: function (username, password) {
        console.log("Call login");

        var errCB = function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        };
        jsk.connect("ws://localhost:8080/ws", "WS", errCB).then(function(app, error) {
            if (!app) {
                console.log("connection failure");
                console.error(error);
            }
            server = app;
            server.ask("login", username.value, password.value).then(function(mySession, err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("logged in");
                    aSession = mySession;
                    var loggedin = "<p>Login successful</p>";
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = loggedin;
                }
            });
        });
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
    <div>
    <Modal.Dialog>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Login</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>

      <Modal.Body>
        <Form horizontal>
          <FormGroup controlId="formControlsEmail">
            <ControlLabel>Email address</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Login (email)" />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="formControlsPassword">
            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl type="password" />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit">
              Login
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal.Dialog>
    </div>
      );
    }
  });

ReactDOM.render(
    <HomePage />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the above code is sound, you appear to be missing a React `createClass` or `Component`.